# TinyMCE: How to add a shortcut to change font size

Tags: javascript, tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to have a shortcut in my TinyMCE edictor to easily change the size of the text. From [TinyMCE Website](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/), there is the command `FontSize` with this description

> Font size of the text. The value passed in should be the font size
>   1-7.

I tried adding this command to my list of others custom shortcuts like this

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+shift+w', 'size_desc', FontSize(5));
```

But it didn't work. I also tried this but without success:

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+shift+w', 'size_desc', '["FontSize", 5]');
```

Also I am confused about the value: why can we only set `1` to `7` and not let say `12px`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+shift+w', 'size_desc', '["FontSize", !1, "5px"]');
```

Also you can create a TinyMce plugin:

1. go to your TinyMCE folder and open note.html
2. In the list of `plugins` add `fontsize_plugin` and in the list of `toolbar` add `fontsizeselect`
3. then add this line juste below toolbar:

   fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 16px 18px
4. open the folder plugins and create in it a folder `fontsize_plugin` and in this filder create a file `plugin.js` in which you should copy paste this:

   ```
   tinymce.PluginManager.add('fontsize_plugin', function (editor, url) {

       editor.addCommand('fontsize_plugin_command', function () {

       var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
       var fontsize = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size', true);

       fontsize = fontsize.split("p", 1)
           fontsize--;

       if (fontsize > 10 && fontsize <= 14) {
           fontsize = 10;
       } else if (fontsize <= 10) {
           fontsize = 18;
       } else {
           fontsize = 14;
       }
       fontsize = fontsize + "px";
       tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('fontsize', false, fontsize);
       });
   editor.addShortcut('ctrl+shift+w', 'fontsize_plugin_desc', 'fontsize_plugin_command');
   });
   ```